# ASP.NET How do I set the position of a control at runtime?

Tags: asp.net

I'm adding a label to a page using the code below, how would I set the position of the label (i.e top right)?

```
Label lbl = new Label();
lbl.Text = "Test";
lbl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
lbl.Font.Size = 10;
lbl.Font.Bold = false;
lbl.Font.Name = "Arial";
Page.Controls.Add(lbl);
```

Thanks

Update:
I really need to avoid using anything that can be altered via editing a file running on the server which is why I'm trying to do this at runtime.

Comment: If you don't want people to edit your ASPX files then consider using a Web Application Project solution with the 'non-updatable UI' option. See http://www.asp.net/learn/hosting/tutorial-15-cs.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Add a PlaceHolder control to your page in the position you want to add the label to and then add the control as a child control of the PlaceHolder eg.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="LabelPlaceHolder" runat="server">
</asp>
```

And then...

```
LabelPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(lbl);
```

Generally, though, dynamically adding controls at run-time is something you want to avoid. As is setting styling through in-line properties (use CSS instead). If you only want the Label to appear under specific circumstances then add it to the page with it's `Visible` property set to `False` and then set it to true to when you want to see it.

Comment: Thanks for that, please see my update above, basically I want to avoid adding anything in the aspx page.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you do all formatting etc. with CSS - so, at runtime all you would specify is a css class for the control and let the browser do the rest.

Comment: I'd agree with that. Putting all the styling in a css file makes the site way easier to maintain. I always find it annoying when people set styles from the code-behind.