# Need to set the location of controls programatically, but cannot find the location property

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, controls

I am trying to move controls, such as gridviews, around on an ASP.net form depending on which button is clicked. I have read previously that using the control.location property can be used to specify new coordinates for the control, but this property doesn't exist. I am using VS2015 Professional.

Is there a certain namespace that needs to be imported to allow this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.Net Web Forms will just render HTML for the browser.  You can set the CSS to the position you desire though:

```
YourControlInstance.Attributes.Item("style") = "POSITION: absolute; LEFT: 100px; TOP: 100px"
```

Answer (score 1):

The [**`Location` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location(v=vs.110).aspx) exists only for [**Windows Forms**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) controls. ASP.NET doesn't implement such capabilities (or at least not in that simple manner) as the controls' positions are determined by the different attributes and CSS-styles you apply to a control.

If you want to freely move around controls you could either try using [**CSS**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1190426/3740093) or you can apparently use a [**placeholder control**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2646031/3740093).